# Issues with bookmarks of files in ubiquity container on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, bookmarks, ubiquitycontainer

I have an iOS app using Core Data. The app can save files locally on the device and in iCloud.
When I create a URL  of the ubiquity container using

```
    FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
```

reading and writing of Core Data files is working fine.

Now I want to store a bookmark of the recently used file in the `UserDefaults`. I create the bookmark using the standard method `url.bookmarkData()`.

When I resolve the url from the bookmark using

```
    var isStale = false
    let url = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookMark, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
```

it looks identical to the url created with `FileManager` as discribed above. The file content can be read appropriately. So far so good.

The problem occurs, when the app tries to save the `managedObjectContext` of my CoreDataStack. The context fires the following error:

`Updating max pk failed: authorization denied with userInfo of { NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 23; }`

Obviously writing access seems to be denied after resolving a ubiquity container URL from a bookmark and I have no idea to solve this problem.